# Why does this Postman script HTTP POST generating an error?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a API call that takes a POST body of

`raw: {"category":1, "fmipstatus":true}` and it is of type JSON.

```
Content-Type is application/json
```

I use Postman to send this API call and I get a 200 response code.

I want to code this call as part of a Postman Pre-request Script

I have the following:

```
 method: 'POST',
  header: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic NDc0OmVmMzAwZThkNGFjNTQ2ZjU3ZjhjYWQ5ZWQwMjUyNGIxYTI5NmQwM2M='
  },
  body: {
            mode: 'raw',
            raw: JSON.stringify( {category: 1, fmipstatus: false} )
    }
```

I always a 401. In the first API through Postman, if I put garbage in there, I also get a 401 response code.

So I am thinking somehow in my Postman script, the body is defined incorrectly.

Does anyone the error?

Answer (score 0):

401 is an authorization error. Something is wrong with your Auth token, either its expired, incorrect, or you're passing it incorrectly.

Comment: but the same call works using Postman and direct API call with and the response code is a 200